# Game Theory and Uniform Distribution question?

Tags: statistics, game-theory

In an Auction , two players are  bidding. Their bids will be a unknown fraction of their valuations. The valuations come from a uniform distribution $$[0,1] $$

If Player 2 bids $$ v/2 $$  and Player 1 bids $$b1<1/2$$

What is the probability player 1 wins ?
Clearly for player 1 to win,players 2 bid has to be less than player 1 bids.
$$P(v/2 < b1)$$ 
$$P(v < 2b1)$$
I follow the question up to this stage.
Now it says since its uniformly distributed the probability player 1 wins is $$2b1$$
Im confused how can you just get 2b1 from the inequality ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: have I incorrectly types the question ? does it not make sense

Comment: I guess it should be $2b1$, not $2b$.

Comment: I guess from the answer that the question actually asked said that $v$ was uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$ and you are to find the probability that player 1 wins given that player 1 bid $b_1$.  (The prior distribution of player 1's valuation is irrelevant for that given information.)  But that is just a guess.  I think you have not accurately stated the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to know the probability that $b_1>v/2$ when $v$ is uniformly distributed and $b_1<1/2$. This is clearly the same as the probability that $2b_1>v$. Now the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ is characterized by the property that for each $0\leq x\leq 1$, a realization from the uniform distribution is smaller than $x$ with probability exactly $x$. In particular, since $v$ is uniformly distributed, the probability that $v<2b_1$ is exactly $2b_1$.